# Pod Result installed with ReactiveCocoa results in 56 compilation errors

Tags: ios, cocoapods, reactive-cocoa

I'm following a Swift tutorial and need to use `ReactiveCocoa`, which I am trying to install with `Cocoapods`.

Very simple Podfile :

```
target 'MyAppTest' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'ReactiveCocoa'
end
```

Everything goes well with Cocoapods (although I don't know why I am getting the 4.0.1 version when the latest should be 5.0.0..? [See here](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/releases)) :

[image]

But once in my project, I simply cannot build it. Here are all the errors I am getting :

[image]

I really don't know what to do...

Cocoapods version is 1.1.1 and Swift is 3.0.2.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your pod cache may be outdated, run a pod repo update and try again.

Comment: You were right, it solved my issue. Thanks a lot.